# No catalina.out from Tomcat in Centos 7 in /var/log/tomcat?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, logging

I installed Tomcat with **`sudo yum install tomcat`**, then I can start it with **`sudo systemctl start tomcat`**.

However, I could not find `catalina.out` in `/var/log/tomcat` (there only some files there):

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat 9171 Oct 25 15:37 catalina.2016-10-25.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat    0 Oct 25 15:22 host-manager.2016-10-25.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat    0 Oct 25 15:22 localhost.2016-10-25.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat 1980 Oct 25 15:31 localhost_access_log.2016-10-25.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat    0 Oct 25 15:22 manager.2016-10-25.log
```

I don't change any configuration of Tomcat just only start it as service.